# Removing MAC OS X and installing clean Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, mac, macosx

I have MacBook Air with an older MAC OS (10.6…).  I’m unable to boot it in to OS X just getting an Apple logo and a little thing keeps spinning below the logo.  I spent tons of time troubleshooting this issue to no avail.  I’ve decided dump MAC OS and install clean version of Ubuntu from scratch.  Is there a way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1):

Make a USB stick with Ubuntu and boot from it. Select "Try Ubuntu".

Then open GParted and select Device → Create Partition Table. This will destroy all partitions on the disk. DON'T DO THIS IF THERE IS ANY DATA YOU WANT TO RECOVER. In this case either copy all data to an external hard drive or to a USB stick or ask me about it in the comments if you're dealing with too much data. If your internal hard drive is less than 2 TiB in size, choose "msdos" (default). If it's bigger than 2 TiB, you might have to choose "gpt", depends on how big you want your partitions to be. If you have disk bigger than 4 TiB, alsways select "gpt". You cannot make partitions bigger than 2 TiB with "msdos" and you cannot make any new partitions after the fist 2 TiB with "msdos". That's why there are the limits of 2 TiB under which it's better to choose "msdos" and 4 TiB over which "gpt" is the way to go. Note that this is a disk specific choice. You will be able connect 6 TiB external hard drives, no problems, even if you choose "msdos" for your internal disk.

Then make the partitions as you wish. Make a swap if you might run out of ram and make ext4 partitions for system, home, whatever you want. If you only want one partition, that's also fine.

Then start the installation and when you get to the point where you're asked where to install Ubuntu, select "something else". Then choose the ext4 partition you made as `/`. This is where your system will go. If you made other partitions for home, etc., also select them.

Comment: Thank you.  I’m having problem with booting from UBUNTU USB stick.  Keep pressing “C” during the boot process but not getting anywhere with it.

--
Best Regards,

Alex

Comment: What do you wish to achieve by pressing `C`?

Comment: Start up from a bootable CD, DVD, or USB thumb drive.

Comment: So this shows you the boot media? Does showing you the boot media not work or are some shown but the usb stick isn't?

Comment: I can show the boot media by holding down “Option” key during startup.  Yes, I can only see MAC HD nothing else.

Comment: Make sure there only exists 1 partition on the USB stick. Some systems have problems with more than 1 partition existing when booting from a USB pen drive, others don't. Format this partition with FAT32 (make sure it is this FS!) and put on Ubuntu again. Also, make sure that booting form external / usb is enabled in the bios settings.